# Lockscreen icon in a Silverlight 8.1 app using WNS

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to have a badge icon + counter on the lock screen for my Silverlight 8.1 app. While migrating the app from SL 8.0 to SL 8.1 I also switched to Windows Notification Service (WNS) to be able to have access to the action center.

Now, I cannot find a way to have the badge logo on the lock screen show the icon of my app.

Steps to reproduce in a blank app:

- Create a new SL 8.1 phone app
- Switch to WNS in WMAppManifest.xml
- Open lock screen settings and see the icon is broken

I can define the badge logo both in the WMAppManifest.xml file:

```
<DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="true">Assets/LockScreen.png</DeviceLockImageURI>
```

Or in the new Package.appxmanifest.xml file:

```
<m3:LockScreen Notification="badge" BadgeLogo="Assets\LockScreen.png" />
```

But in both case, it doesn't work (icon is missing):

[image: wp-icon-missing]

I also tried various image resolution but that doesn't solve the issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our Silverlight 8.1 app with lockscreen notification support and WNS we have used:

- in WMAppManifest.xml

```
<DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\Tiles\LockImage.png</DeviceLockImageURI>
```

- in Package.appxmanifest

```
<m3:LockScreen Notification="badgeAndTileText" BadgeLogo="Assets\BadgeLogo.png" />
```

The icons we use - they need to be only white-to-transparent colors. LockImage.png is 38x38m, BadgeLogo.png is 58x58.

**Note:** We don't have in the

```
<Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Notification_IconCount" ... />
```

tag in WMAppManifest.xml - if you define both **Notification="badgeAndTileText"** in Package.appxmanifest and **LockScreen_Notification_IconCount** in WMAppManifest.xml, your app will have two entries in the Lockscreen app settings combobox and that's something you don't want.

In case of Silverlight 8.1 app with WNS just define the lock screen settings in Package.appxmanifest and it should work just fine.

Comment: Perfect Martin ! That was it ! Having the <Extension> element (from the SL 8.0 version) was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your logo has some sort of `Transparency` in it.

It's been clearly explained throughout this article.

[Lock screen notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207048(v=vs.105).aspx)